# got `{}` when set a field in mongodb to `undefined` using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm facing a weird problem
I'm using `mongoose 5.12.8`, I try to delete a user's image with this route

```
router.delete('/users/me/avatar', auth, async(req, res) => {
    try {
        req.user.avatarObj = undefined
        await req.user.save()
        res.send({ message: "Deleted user's avatar" })
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).send(error.message)
    }
});
```

but when I use `get` route, i got `req.user.avatarObj` is still an empty object `{}`

```
//get user avatar
router.get('/users/:id/avatar', async(req, res) => {
    try {
        const user = await User.findById(req.params.id);

        console.log(user.avatarObj) // print {} ?????????
        console.log(user) //user has no avatarObj field

        if (user && user.avatarObj) {
            res.set('Content-Type', user.avatarObj.contentType);
            res.send(user.avatarObj.data);
        } else {
            throw new Error('Not found user or image');
        }
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(404).send({ error: err.message });
    }
});
```

this is my `userSchema`

```
avatarObj: {
        data: Buffer,
        contentType: String
    }
```

and some middleware

```
//hash plain text password before saving
userSchema.pre('save', async function(next) {
    const user = this
    if (user.isModified('password')) {
        user.password = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, 10)
    }
    next()
});

//remove all tasks before remove user
userSchema.pre('remove', async function(next) {
    await Task.deleteMany({ owner: this._id })
    next()
});
```

My question is: Why `user.avatarObj` is still an empty object?
Thank you guys!

Comment: Why do you assigning `undefined` instead of just remove that field?

Comment: i'm doing a delete user's avatar feature sir! user has avatar and they can delete them :D